# xPath search with as2 and ignore case

Tags: xml, xpath, case, actionscript-2

in this moment in my aplication I search in a XML for a string, but i don't know how can I do for ignore case, for example if I search 'Test' I need to show all words with upper and lower case.

I use the xPath library for as2, and I have something like this:

```
var searchedText = 'Search test';

query = "//*[contains(text(), '" + searchedText + "')]";
result = XPath.selectNodes (myLoadedXML, query);
```

Any solution?

I use as2 because it's a modification of an old project ^^.

Thanks a lot